# How to run a command at login

Tags: command-line, login, ls, df

So I've been looking around and I can find ways to run commands every time you open a new terminal and inadvertently figured out how to make a continuous loop of opening terminals.

I've edited .bashrc .bash_login .bash_profile .bash_alias .profile (each separately) and nothing has worked besides the .profile and .bash_alias but this happens EVERY time I open a new terminal. I even made my own scrip and added it to the /.config/startup/ .desktop Nothing..

All I want is when I login a terminal opens (already set in startup app) then run something like ls -l and df -h or whatever else I could want further down the line.

Even better if there's some way to open another terminal after that to work from and without creating that continuous loop..

This is what I want my desktop to look like at login:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Undo the changes you've done to `.profile` and `.bashrc` . You don't need them unless your intention is to have something run every single time you open terminal, not just single window upon login

Answer (score 1):

What you want is this:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "df;bash"'
```

The `gnome-terminal` by default runs any *single* command passed to it as single shot and exits. Thus you want to call a *single* command capable of running multiple, which is what `bash -c "df;bash"` does - it will run df, then spawn another instance of `bash` and prevent window from exiting one `df` completes execution.

Finally, add that to startup applications